# launch iOS app on CallKit response when screen is locked for zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

**I do have a question about using Zoom in combination with CallKit for iOS.**
Basically, when we want to start a meeting we want to notify client using CallKit as its going to present him with native experience for answering the call. In order to notify the client we use PushKit service, so basically steps would be:

1. Host starts the meeting through website
2. Client gets notified through PushKit
3. When PushKit notifications is received we start CallKit
4. When user answers we want to show Zoom meeting room

Now, using CallKit there are 3 different states which we noticed that are different:

1. When app is in foreground, we did managed to normally just start
   Zoom view controller
2. When app is in background we did managed to start Zoom view
   controller
3. When app is killed and device is locked CallKit will only start
   Audio call and won’t automatically trigger our app (**which is
   expected behavior**) but we cannot configure Zoom to work with
   AVAudioSession which is started from CallKit.

Is there any way how we can integrate Zoom to work with CallKit?